# Error: Type CodePush does not have 'ɵmod' property

Tags: cordova-plugins, visual-studio-cordova, code-push

Hi I was trying the codepush plugin in my cordova app.

I created the new blank app with Cordova angular and I install the plugins.
The problem is whenever I start using the plugin there's no error but after the splash screen, the scree turns white.
When I inspect it
`Error: Type CodePush does not have 'ɵmod' property.` shows.